# MySQL INSERT INTO with dual condition for IF NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert a new record if the email address does not exist in list_email.email_addr AND  not exist in list_no_email.email_addr

```
INSERT INTO list_email(fname, lname, email_addr) VALUES('bob', 'schmoe', 'bogus@bogus.com'), ('mary', 'lamb', 'hoe@me.com');
SELECT email_addr FROM list_email
WHERE NOT EXIST(
SELECT email_addr FROM email_addr WHERE email_addr = $post_addr
) 
WHERE NOT IN (
SELECT email_addr FROM list_no_email WHERE email_addr = $post_addr
)LIMIT 1


**************************** mysql tables ******************************

mysql> desc list_email;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| list_name  | varchar(55)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fname      | char(50)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lname      | char(50)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email_addr | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc list_no_email;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| date_in    | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| email_addr | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

*************************** error   ****************************

```
INSERT INTO list_email(fname, lname, email_addr) VALUES('bob', 'schmoe', 'bogus@bogus.com'), ('mary', 'lamb', 'hoe@me.com'); SELECT email_addr FROM list_email WHERE NOT EXIST( SELECT email_addr FROM email_addr WHERE email_addr = $post_addr )  WHERE NOT IN ( SELECT email_addr FROM list_no_email WHERE email_addr = $post_addr )LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT email_addr FROM email_addr WHERE email_addr = $post_addr )  WHERE NOT IN ' at line 1
```

*********************  without ;  ******************************

```
mysql> INSERT INTO list_email(fname, lname, email_addr) VALUES('bob', 'schmoe', 'bogus@bogus.com'), ('mary', 'lamb', 'hoe@me.com')
    -> SELECT email_addr FROM list_email AS tmp
    -> WHERE NOT EXIST(
    -> SELECT email_addr FROM email_addr WHERE email_addr = $post_addr
    -> )
    -> WHERE NOT IN (
    -> SELECT email_addr FROM list_no_email WHERE email_addr = $post_addr
    -> )LIMIT 1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT email_addr FROM list_email AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXIST(
SELECT email_addr FROM' at line 2
```

Comment: And the problem is... what?

Comment: @Itay How to do it. I get to that point and my brain turns to mush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace**

```
WHERE NOT EXIST(
```

**With**

```
WHERE email_addr NOT IN(
```

**EDIT**

**Replace**

```
SELECT email_addr FROM list_email
WHERE NOT IN
(
    SELECT email_addr FROM email_addr WHERE email_addr = $post_addr
) 
WHERE NOT IN
(
    SELECT email_addr FROM list_no_email WHERE email_addr = $post_addr
)LIMIT 1
```

**with**

```
SELECT email_addr FROM list_email
WHERE NOT IN
(
    SELECT email_addr FROM email_addr WHERE email_addr = $post_addr
    UNION ALL
    SELECT email_addr FROM list_no_email WHERE email_addr = $post_addr
)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: http://paste.ee/p/BCBGY it's not exactly working, I am sure that I am screwing it up though.

Comment: @brad your `SELECT email_addr FROM list_email(SELECT email_addr) AS tmp` this conditions is wrong...remove `(SELECT email_addr)` line and try

Comment: now move on to next error....you have two where clause that is incorrect....use `left join` or `union all` to get all the email in single `where` clause

Comment: it's doing the same thing. It gets to the end of the insert and borks   http://paste.ee/p/RYluh

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO list_email($username.$rowname, fname, lname, list_email) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
     SELECT email_addr FROM list_email AS tmp
     WHERE email_addr NOT IN(
         SELECT email_addr FROM list_email WHERE email_addr = $post_addr)
         WHERE email_addr NOT IN (SELECT email_addr FROM list_no_email 
                                  WHERE email_addr = $post_addr)
     LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT email_addr) AS tmp
     WHERE email_addr NOT IN(
         SELECT email_a' at line 1

Comment: @brad I dunno what do you mean by `SELECT email_addr` whould you please explain what do want from this?

Comment: select the column eail_addr? I am trying to compare the new email address being inserted with both list_email.email_addr and list_no_email.email_addr

Comment: It still does not like the select.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO list_email
  (fname, lname, email_addr)
SELECT ins.*
FROM
  ( SELECT 'bob' AS fname, 
           'schmoe' AS lname, 
           'bogus@bogus.com' AS email_addr
    FROM dual
  UNION ALL                               -- for every row to be inserted
    SELECT 'mary', 'lamb', 'hoe@me.com'
    FROM dual 
                                          -- add another UNION ALL .. FROM dual
  ) AS ins
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1 
        FROM email_addr AS e 
        WHERE e.email_addr = ins.email_addr
      )
  AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1 
        FROM list_no_email AS ne 
        WHERE ne.email_addr = ins.email_addr
      ) ;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the union works? using static data the code works perfect, but trying to integrate it into php using variables, I am just not catching how to make it work. Would the static email addresses become separate table.column names?

Comment: The code I gave is an example, if you want to insert 2 rows. You can extend it to 3, 4, ..., 20, ... I assumed you wanted to insert only a few rows at a time. If you want to insert them in the thousands, it's cumbersome.