# PhP Upload CSV into MySQL with a complex duel NOT EXIST

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I am trying to create a script that uploads email addresses from a csv file but also checks to see if that address already exist in 2 different tables prior to inserting. 
I have this query that works perfect :

```
INSERT INTO list_email (fname, lname, email_addr)
SELECT ins.* FROM ( SELECT 'bob' AS fname,
'schmoe' AS lname,
'bogus@bogus.com' AS email_addr
FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'mary', 'lamb', 'hoe@me.com'
FROM dual ) AS ins WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT 1
FROM list_email AS e
WHERE e.email_addr = ins.email_addr
) AND NOT EXISTS
( SELECT 1
FROM list_no_email AS ne
WHERE ne.email_addr = ins.email_addr );
```

But since this is a file upload script, for obvious reasons bogus@bogus.com is just isn't going to work. I need to compare 'each' inbound record, not just one. So it must be $email_addr bound for the list_email.email_addr column (if it doesn't already exist)
I just can't seem to access $_FILES['userfile'] key to get to the data such as $email_addr to do the comparison. Are var_dump() of $_FILES show test.csv with 'userfile' as a key, but I can't get inside it. $_POST has my row_name and works fine.

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <p> Give a unique name for your campaign </p>
        <input name="row_name" type="text">
        <br/>
        <input name="userfile" type="file">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">

  </form>
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname"; //Data Source Name = Mysql
$db = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password); //Connect to DB
//var_dump($_FILES);
//var_dump($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['userfile']) && isset($_POST['row_name'])){
        $insert = array(NULL, $data[0]." ".$data[1], $data[0],$data[1],$data[2]);
        var_dump($insert);
        $do = $db->prepare(
                "INSERT INTO list_email(list_name, fname, lname, email_addr)
                SELECT ins.*
                FROM(
                 SELECT $data[1] AS fname,
                 $lname AS lname,
                 $data[3] AS email_addr
                 FROM dual
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT $data[1], $data[2], $data[3]
                 FROM dual
                ) AS ins
                WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                 SELECT 1
                 FROM list_email AS e
                 WHERE e.email_addr = ins.email_addr
                )
                AND NOT EXISTS(
                 SELECT 1
                 FROM list_no_email AS ne
                 WHERE ne.email_addr = ins.email_addr
                )"
                );
        $csv_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        // exit if file fail
        if ( ! is_file( $csv_file ) )
                exit('File not found.');
        if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
                //var_dump($insert);
                $do->execute($insert);
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
}
exit( "Complete!" );
?>
</body>
</html>
```

*************************  var_dump()  ************************************

```
    Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/wemail1/www/pages/campaign-build.inc.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/wemail1/www/pages/campaign-build.inc.php on line 35

NULL array(1) { ["userfile"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "test1.csv"
+["type"]=> string(24) "application/vnd.ms-excel" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14)
+"/tmp/php5k0ppx" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(76) } }
> no values ^^
> var_dump($_FILES);
```

**********************  *table*  ***************************

```
mysql> desc list_email;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| list_name  | varchar(55)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fname      | char(50)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lname      | char(50)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email_addr | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc list_no_email;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| date_in    | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| email_addr | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)




http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584541/mysql-insert-into-with-dual-condition-for-if-not-exist
```

Comment: `$fname = $_FILES[0]; $lname = $_FILES[1]; $post_addr = $_FILES[2];` Where exactly is `$_FILES[0]` comming from? (same for **1** and **2**)

Comment: @Tikkes I gave it this validation right in fron of the other and I get the same error.  if(is_array($_FILES['userfile'])){, I also tried passing it as an additional parameter and that failed too.

Comment: `$_FILES` does not have a key `0`, `1` or `2`. It uses `tmp_name`, ...

Comment: I just took a look at the edits you made in your code and I wonder if you read my answer. `$data` does not work in prepared statements. Check my answer again and read it carefully because what you are doing is still wrong.

Comment: @Tikkes how would I access the values in tmp_name? by key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I cleaned up your code a bit. The error you mension is cause by the fact that you call `$_FILES[0]`, `$_FILES[1]` and `$_FILES[2]`. There is no value here and thus this is null.

Furthermore, your code has a bunch of stuff that is not needed at all.

ALSO: look at the prepared statements and how you fill variables there!

Let me explain:

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname"; //Data Source Name = Mysql
$db = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password); //Connect to DB
if (isset($_POST['userfile']) && isset($_POST('row_name']))){
    //$rowname = $_POST['row_name']; (do you need this? You never call this anywhere below)

    //Dont know why this is here
    //$fname = $_FILES[0]; 
    //$lname = $_FILES[1]; 
    //$post_addr = $_FILES[2];

    //PDO does not work with $var, instead use :var and fill the var before executing the query
    $do = $db->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO list_email(list_name, fname, lname, email_addr)
            SELECT ins.*
            FROM(
             SELECT :fname AS fname,
             :lname AS lname,
             :post_addr AS email_addr
             FROM dual
             UNION ALL
             SELECT :fname, :lname, :post_addr
             FROM dual
            ) AS ins
            WHERE NOT EXISTS(
             SELECT 1
             FROM list_email AS e
             WHERE e.email_addr = ins.email_addr
            )
            AND NOT EXISTS(
             SELECT 1
             FROM list_no_email AS ne
             WHERE ne.email_addr = ins.email_addr
            )"
            );

            $do->bindParam(':fname', $fname);
            $do->bindParam(':lname', $lname);
            $do->bindParam(':post_addr', $post_addr);

    $csv_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    // exit if file fail
    if ( ! is_file( $csv_file ) )
            exit('File not found.'); //exit = bad practise, use proper error handling
    if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) 
    {
            //$insert = array(NULL, $data[0]." ".$data[1], $data[0],$data[1],$data[2]); (what is this? what does it do?)

            //Fill the variables needed for the query
            $fname = "your desired value";
            $lname = "your desired value";
            $post_addr = "your desired value";
            //Execute the query
            $do->execute();
    }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
else {
 print "Something went wrong while trying IsSet";
}
?>
```

Lets take a look at this:

```
$fname = "your desired value";
$lname = "your desired value";
$post_addr = "your desired value";
```

You need your values here obviously, these will come from the line you read. 
So in example, this will be:

```
$fname = $data[0];
$lname = $data[1];
$post_addr = $data[2];
```

Besides all of this, you SQL query will fail too.
You want to insert data into your `list_email` requesting **4** columns but only passing **3** variables.

I also do not see why you would select your variables you passed **twice** from `dual`

**EDIT**

As I stated, you SQL query is wrong.

I've updated this a little bit.
**Where does list_name come from?**

I've now added **MISSING_VALUE** in the updated query:

```
INSERT INTO list_email(list_name, fname, lname, email_addr)
            SELECT ins.*
            FROM(

SELECT ins.*
FROM
(
SELECT 
    'MISSING VALUE' as MISSING_VALUE
    :fname AS fname,
    :lname AS lname,
    :post_addr AS email_addr
FROM dual
) as ins 
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM list_email AS e 
    WHERE e.email_addr = ins.email_addr)
AND 
NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM list_no_email AS ne
    WHERE ne.email_addr = ins.email_addr))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, though after making your recommended changes, I get no error, but no data ever makes it into the database. I updated the code above to reflect the changes.

Comment: That's because your SQL query is still wrong. You want to insert 4 values but only get 3 from your select.

Comment: I've updated the code and the SQL query can be found below, look at **MISSING_VALUE**. If this was helpful, please accept my answer.

Comment: http://paste.ee/p/BnOYe  this query is valid and does what it is supposed to do, and tested 'but' instead of static data I need variable to accommodate for the uploaded file. What you refer to as 'missing' is what I am trying to retrieve from the posted file or $_FILES[]

Comment: And what does that value contain? Filename? Something else? Your query was invadid at first, you did request 4 columns yet only returning 3 variables. This (from the paste) seems to be fixed by you know. Also, you do a `union` on the select from dual which is not neccesary at all. What is not working still? And what do you expect to get from `$_FILES` to put into your database?